# Visual studio 2022 for Mac (M1) showing purple terminal and not running program?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

When I run my program in Visual studio it just comes up with a completely purple and blank terminal window titled "TerminalPad-TerminalPad-3" and doesn't allow me to interact with my program. It's a simple program that allows the user to enter values into a queue, the code is fine - it worked perfectly yesterday. The purple terminal comes up with every program I try to open, not just this one.

Not sure whether this issue is caused by todays update (17.4) or not but it worked fine before the update. I've tried completely uninstalling VS and Re-installing everything again, but that did nothing.

Any idea why this is happening or how to solve? Only seen one other person have this problem and no one had replied with a solution

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (14/11/22):
The following fix worked for me but only for a few days, then the purple terminal came back out of nowhere. I have no idea why, if anybody has any further suggestions please let me know!

--Fixed (9/11/22)--
I downloaded an app uninstaller (specifically https://nektony.com/mac-app-cleaner) to completely delete all related files and cache data from Visual Studio, then restarted my MacBook and re-installed it. It Works fine now.

The first time I tried deleting and reinstalling, I went through the files manually to delete them. I must have missed some so the cache wasn't fully deleted. If anyone else has this problem, use the uninstaller!