# Visual Studio 2022 Mac Console shows purple screen

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

This is my first question, I think, let me know if have to do in other way.

Past weekend my Visual Studio for Mac, currently v17.4, doesn't works even running a clean new console project, with default Hello World string.

It shows a blank Purple screen and no errors or any other output.

After read this question
[Visual studio 2022 for Mac (M1) showing purple terminal and not running program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367348/visual-studio-2022-for-mac-m1-showing-purple-terminal-and-not-running-program)

I removed completelly using MS scripts https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2022

Downloaded and install latest version, but today is happening again.

I'm running Mac OS 12.6 on MacBook Air M1 2020.

Any idea about what could be happening or how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: The purple screen is for the terminal window or something else? There will likely be errors in the IDE log ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio/17.0

Comment: Yes it's the terminal window, the console.

A simple test, from a blank new Console project, with a Hello World, made changes in logs:
Ide....log
LSPClient....log
VSMonitor....log

I have not much idea, but the only entries that catch my attention, are these en VSMonitor, because there are a lot like these, but sometimes are very different...

Will Paste in next message.

Comment: [2022-11-18 16:40:45Z][16]        : Calculating max sent archive cache size, default is 10240MB


[2022-11-18 16:40:45Z][16] INFO   : Purging prior sent archives older than 5 days or total more than 10737418240


[2022-11-18 16:40:45Z][16]        : Can keep unsent coredumps on disk, 10240 needed with 468596 available

Comment: Probably best to use the Report a Problem dialog in Visual Studio for Mac, then that can upload all the IDE Logs to Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a solution to the Console purple screen in Mac the solution is here...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Application-Output-purple-window/10180164

Remove contents for your Visual Studio version in these folders:

- ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio/17.3
- ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/17.3/
- ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio/17.3/

It worked in my case.